# Is it possible to print a R flexdashboard to a PDF?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Furthermore, can you loop the print out based on a specific variable?

Say for example I have one view for a vendor. How can I print out a PDF view iteratively based on this vendor? Basically, it would be a unique view for each vendor

Comment: Relevant, but maybe not the current state of the art: https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/06/28/printing-from-flex-dashboard/

Comment: Flexdashboard is designed for interactive exploration. I'd rather use an external markdown for PDF publishing (they can share code thru the use of common functions in an external .R file)

Comment: As mentioned by HubertL, flexdashboard is by design a html page that can embed interactive elements. You can print to pdf via a browser or knit to pdf. Nonetheless, I would create a non-flexdashboard Rmd for static output. To create "unique" views for a vendor, read up on parameterised reports. Supplying a parameter for a vendor (= params$vendor) you can filter your data, etc. to populate the Rmd output. You can create a render script that basically loads the Rmd and passes the (set of) parameter(s) to create your designed output: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. The issue I have with RMarkdown is that I haven't found much documentation on created a landscape file with plots/views shown on different "boxes" of a given page, please correct me if I am wrong however

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing! I understand people saying it's not what it's intended for but sometimes you just need to use a workaround! Your options are...

```
#make a PNG
webshot::webshot("your_flexdashboard.html", "your_new_file.png")

#convert PNG to PDF
magick::image_write(
  image = magick::image_read("your_new_file.png"), 
  format = "pdf", 
  path =  "your_new_file.pdf"
)
```

Or... (works best if one page)

```
psycModel::html_to_pdf("your_flexdashboard.html")
```

Let me know if more explanation is needed. The first option works for plotly hthml widgets but for me didn't work for DT tables.

To loop this simply use a for loop and list of your dashboards.

```
FILES<-list.files("flexfolder")

for (FILE in FILES){
psycModel::html_to_pdf(FILE)
}
```

Comment: I couldn't try your first way but the second one does not create pdf with the flexdashboard colors.